# Inheritance, expected type-specifier before error

Tags: c++, inheritance

Well I'm trying to figure out inheritance in c++, and I'm getting a compile time error error: expected type- specifier before 'Pawn'. I get this on the following line

```
Piece * p = new Pawn(c);
```

***I removed this code because I got worried about people using my code for the assignment I was doing at the time. I apologize if this caused any inconvenience, if you have any specific questions contact me.***

I'm aware there may be some other errors but This is the one I'm at a loss with. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: looks like you missed `#include "Pawn.h"` in your Pawn.cpp

Comment: Please show the code that surrounds the erroneous line.  Also, consider simplifying your example code (see http://sccee.org).

Comment: Please also give your main program

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the file that has the statement

```
Piece * p = new Pawn(c);
```

you seem to forget to include corresponding header files.

Comment: ok, I didn't know what to put up, people always tell me to post more, so I posted more, I'm sorry, Yes I'm amazed you could tell that. thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

I had encountered a similar problem. It turned out I copied and pasted from a previous class and forgot to update my #ifndef statement at the top of my new header file. The compiler was ignoring my new header file because I told it to. D'oh!